# Disable an eclipse plugin that causes a conflict with a plugin in my Feature

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jsdt

I have an eclipse feature which essentially depends upon the Eclipse for Javascript Web Developers platform (it depends upon many plugins in there). However, one set of plugins causes a conflict with my feature's plugins: jsdt.debug.*

So, the question is, when a user installs / runs this feature, is there a way I can disable the 4 jsdt.debug plugins which cause this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't delete those plugins if you dont want to use them, or you can even uninstall them from Help->Software Updates and go to installed plugins and select uninstall.

Comment: Sorry to be clear this is from a Eclipse Plugin Development perspective, not a Eclipse Plugin User perspective. I am developing the feature ... and I want to add an installation task to the feature, which disables the jsdt.debug plugins, if they are present.

This probably isn't possible ... a plugin / feature likely does not have control over plugins outside of it.